# Running a bunch of methods by string and receiving a value

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have a bunch of methods that return a bool value. These are tests that check for n conditions. If one of them returns YES, the condition is invalid. Something like

```
- (BOOL) areNumbersInvalid {

}

- (BOOL) areNumbersBigger {

}

// etc...
```

There are hundreds of methods.

Actually I would run them like this:

```
if ([self areNumbersInvalid]) {
   [self failed];
}

if ([self areNumbersBigger]) {
   [self failed];
}

// etc
```

Imagine hundreds of lines like this for every method.

Than I thought I could have all method names on an array and use something like

```
  [methods enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent
                            usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

                              NSString *oneMethod = (NSString *)obj;
                              SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(oneMethod);

                              BOOL failed = [self  performSelector:selector withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];

                              if (failed) {
                                // do something
                              }


                            }];
```

but I cannot use this line

```
BOOL failed = [self  performSelector:selector withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];
```

because this performSelector line expects a void return will not return a BOOL value

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [you can use NSInvocation for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492033/return-value-for-performselector):

```
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
                            [[someInstance class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector]];
[invocation setSelector:selector];
[invocation setTarget:someInstance];
[invocation invoke];
BOOL returnValue;
[invocation getReturnValue:&returnValue];
NSLog(@"Returned %@", returnValue? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Comment: P E R F E C T  ! ! !   THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

create a class property as

```
@property BOOL failed;
```

In those methods, update the failed property accordingly.
And after executing

```
[self  performSelector:selector withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];
```

check for failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the method signature at compile time (`BOOL (*)(id, SEL)` in this case), you can do this

```
SEL selector = // ...
id obj = // ...
BOOL (*imp)(id, SEL);
imp = (BOOL (*)(id, SEL))[obj methodForSelector:selector];
BOOL result = imp(obj, selector); // call it
```

less overhead compare to NSInvocation