# How can I return any type value like -performSelector?

Tags: objective-c

The return-type of `-performSelector` method is `id`, and I found this in an Apple document:

> For methods that return anything other than an object, use NSInvocation.

But the following code works well:

`BOOL boolValue = (BOOL)[self performSelector:@selector(boolValue)];`

It can return `id`, `BOOL`, `NSInteger`, etc. How can I do that? Because casting a `BOOL` or `NSInteger` to `id` in the return statement caused an error:

> Cast of 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC

I know it is not good to do that and I also know how to use NSInvocation. I just want to know how does `-performSelector` method implemented.

Finally, I found it...

https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-706/runtime/NSObject.mm

Comment: casting an _object_ as _primitive_ is not really correct logically.

Comment: @holex Yes, I know. I just want to know how to do that.

Comment: you can send back an _object_ only, like `NSNumber` and you can store a _primitive_ value in them e.g. `BOOL`, `NSInteger`, `Float64` etc... and when you have the object you can convert it back to _primitives_. neither too elegant and too safe – but quick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to use `NSInvocation` as said in other answers, you can also use call the implementation function directly if you know the type at compile-time.

```
SEL sel = @selector(boolValue);
IMP imp = [self methodForSelector:sel];
BOOL value = ((BOOL (*)(id, SEL))imp)(self, sel);
```

You have to cast `imp` to the correct type, otherwise it is undefined behavior and crash if you are lucky.

Comment: This is the safest approach with 32-/64-bit and ARC, since the exact size of each parameter and whether it should be passed `strong` or `weak` can be specified this way.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get the return value, use [NSInvocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/Tasks/invocations.html) instead of perform selector. Below is the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492033/return-value-for-performselector):-

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"someSelector");
if ([someInstance respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
                                [[someInstance class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector]];
    [invocation setSelector:selector];
    [invocation setTarget:someInstance];
    [invocation invoke];
    float returnValue;
    [invocation getReturnValue:&returnValue];
    NSLog(@"Returned %f", returnValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your code does not work: to see how it is broken, run it on a 64-bit system. On 32-bit systems it works by an unfortunate accident, [but on 64-bit systems the upper half of the returned value will contain garbage data](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/288663-bool-returned-via-performselctor-not-bool-on-64-bit-system.html). This is because `BOOL` will be cast to `id` before returning the result to you, which will cause undefined behavior.

To do it right, check one of many answers on Stack Overflow - for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10973879/335858).

Comment: I don't recommend `NSInvocation`. It's hard to get right with ARC, for instance with `__autoreleasing` (such as `(NSError **)error`).

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote only works because you are abusing types. The BOOL returned by the selector boolValue is being cast to an id, and then back to a BOOL. This is risky, because the length of an id field is not guaranteed to be the same as the length of a BOOL.

ARC does extra handling for id return types, and therefore this kind of abuse will simply not work, which is why you're getting the compilation error. There is a bridge hack that should make it work, but I hesitate to repeat it here, because it's completely unnecessary and will result in truly awful code.

For more details on the correct way to do this, see this question: [iPhone: performSelector with BOOL parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075620/iphone-performselector-with-bool-parameter)